# VueJS MEVN stack - axios put 'Error: Request failed with status code 404' although Postman 'put' works fine

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-router

I'm following a tutorial to build a full stack app using VueJS and the MEVN stack.  I have

- a) built mongo db
- b) build api back end with one mongoose model 'Student'
- c) got the back end api running at localhost:4000/api
- d) got the front end running with VueJS and Axios to read data from
  the api
- e) got READ, CREATE and DELETE working fine from my VueJS app
- f) UPDATE is not working
- g) Postman PUT is working fine though, so I know the back end is
  fine.

Back end routes are

```js
const express = require('express');
const studentRoute = express.Router();

// model
let StudentModel = require('../models/Student');

studentRoute.route('/create-student').post((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('creating one student at /create-student')
  StudentModel.create(req.body, (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    return next(error)
  } else {
    console.log(`student created ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)
    res.json(data)
  }
})
});

studentRoute.route('/').get((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('GET all students')
    StudentModel.find((error, data) => {
     if (error) {
       return next(error)
     } else {
       res.json(data)
     }
   })
 })

studentRoute.route('/edit-student/:id').get((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('get one student at /edit-student/:id')
   StudentModel.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error)
    } else {
      res.json(data)
    }
  })
})

// Update
studentRoute.route('/update-student/:id').post((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`attempting to update one student with id ${req.params.id}`)
  console.log(`request body = `)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
  console.log(req.body)
  StudentModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
     { $set: req.body },
   (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(`an error has taken place`)
      return next(error);
    } else {
      res.json(data)
      console.log('Student successfully updated!')
    }
  })
})

// Delete
studentRoute.route('/delete-student/:id').delete((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('delete one student at /delete-student/:id')
  StudentModel.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({
        msg: data
      })
    }
  })
})

module.exports = studentRoute;
```

front end update code is

```js
<template>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3 class="text-center">Update Student</h3>
            <form @submit.prevent="handleUpdateForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="student.name" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" v-model="student.email" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="student.phone" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import axios from "axios";
export default class EditComponent extends Vue {

  student!: {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: ''
  }

  data() {
    return {
      student: { }
    }
  }

  created() {
    let apiURL = `http://localhost:4000/api/edit-student/${this.$route.params.id}`;
    axios.get(apiURL).then((res) => {
        this.student = res.data;
    })
  }

  handleUpdateForm() {
    let id = this.$route.params.id
    let apiURL = `http://localhost:4000/api/update-student/${this.$route.params.id}`;
    console.log(`attempt to update student at url`)
    console.log(apiURL)
    console.log(`with id`)
    console.log(id)
    console.log(`attempt to update student ${JSON.stringify(this.student)}`)
    axios.put(apiURL, this.student)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(`response is ${res}`)
        this.$router.push('/view')
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error when updating student')
        console.log(error)
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

when I use Postman I get this response from the api

```
attempting to update one student with id 6119d671cc9ce131207bd37c
request body = 
{"_id":"6119d671cc9ce131207bd37c","name":"PHIL","email":"philanderson888@hotmail.com","phone":7888849991,"__v":0}{ _id: '6119d671cc9ce131207bd37c',
  name: 'PHIL',
  email: 'philanderson888@hotmail.com',
  phone: 7888849991,
  __v: 0 }
Student successfully updated!
```

when I use VueJS to update my Student I get the following error from this code

```js
// Update
studentRoute.route('/update-student/:id').post((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`attempting to update one student with id ${req.params.id}`)
  console.log(`request body = `)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
  console.log(req.body)
  StudentModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
     { $set: req.body },
   (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(`an error has taken place`)
      return next(error);
    } else {
      res.json(data)
      console.log('Student successfully updated!')
    }
  })
})
```

```
attempt to update student at url
EditComponent.vue?720f:29 http://localhost:4000/api/update-student/6119d671cc9ce131207bd37c
EditComponent.vue?720f:30 with id
EditComponent.vue?720f:31 6119d671cc9ce131207bd37c
EditComponent.vue?720f:32 attempt to update student {"_id":"6119d671cc9ce131207bd37c","name":"PHIL","email":"phil@phil.com","phone":123,"__v":0}
xhr.js?b50d:177 PUT http://localhost:4000/api/update-student/6119d671cc9ce131207bd37c 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?b50d:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?b50d:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?5270:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js?0a06:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js?0a06:87
wrap @ bind.js?1d2b:9
handleUpdateForm @ EditComponent.vue?720f:33
eval @ EditComponent.vue?2308:5
eval @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:1400
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6988
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6997
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:347
EditComponent.vue?720f:39 error when updating student
EditComponent.vue?720f:40 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:62)
```

I'm aware mongo has updated their methods for handling updates and have tried the following

1)

```
  StudentModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
     { $set: req.body },
   (error, data) => {
```

2. 

```js
  StudentModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id},
     { $set: req.body },
   (error, data) => {
```

3. 

```js
  StudentModel.updateOne({_id:req.params.id},
     { $set: req.body },
   (error, data) => {
```

In each case I am getting the error above and in each case Postman works fine.  So there's a problem with the URL being formed and I'm not sure what it is???

Your help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Philip

Also, just in case it is relevant, here is the back end `app.js`

```js
let express = require('express'),
  cors = require('cors'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  database = require('./database'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Connect mongoDB
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
//mongoose.set('useFindAndModify',false);
mongoose.connect(database.db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Database connected")
  },
  error => {
    console.log("Database could't be connected to: " + error)
  }
)

const studentAPI = require('../api/routes/student.route')
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cors());

// API
app.use('/api', studentAPI)

// Create port
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Connected to port ' + port)
})

const logUsage = (logCode) => {
  console.log(`http serving with code ${logCode}`)
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`logging data in 'next'`)
  next(logUsage(200));
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log('in app.use')
  console.error(err.message);
  if (!err.statusCode) err.statusCode = 500;
  res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace `post` in update route with `put`

Comment: Thank you - that was simple!  I thought I had pretty much got it working, so thank you so much!!!!  Really appreciate this.

Comment: Just that simple tweak means now the application is working perfectly.  !!!!!

Comment: fao @nikola-pavicevic